# architecture assessment for input form options in ng6?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to understand Angular 6 input forms from an architecture assessment perspective. Template-driven forms are one option. Based on what I've read online, template-driven forms are generally considered "starter forms" or maybe forms that are more natural for developers transitioning from AngularJs.

Reactive Forms are another option. Based on what I've read online, Reactive Forms are generally considered more capable, flexible and testable than Template-driven forms. Does this appear to be an accurate assessment?

I've only glanced at the documentation, but it appesrs that Dynamic forms provide a quick and easy way to completely generate forms from only metadata.

So it seems that Dynamic Forms would be the starting point for architectural assessment b/c this approach would simplify the development process by eliminating most of the UI work. Have you ever run into any particular scenarios where Dynamic Forms fell short?  Or are there generally straightforward and structured ways to accommodate potential limitations with Dynamic Forms?

It seems that Reactive Forms should generally be considered as the preferred input forms architecture over Template-driven forms for a large scale enterprise application. Can you please confirm this statement?

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with you on this.

**THE GOOD: Yes!** Reactive Forms are generally more capable, flexible and testable than Template-driven forms. You can add custom validators, async validators, generate forms with a model in mind, add controls or control groups to your form dynamically and do all these sorts of things with Reactive Forms.

Dynamic Forms are just an extension of Reactive Forms. They do allow you to generate forms just by configuration. But it might be a bit tricky to set them up. Considering different types of Form Fields there are. In the example that Angular has [demonstrated here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form), it's just for an `input` and a `select` list. But what if the form also has `radio` buttons, an auto-complete list with chips and several other things of this sort. I've never used a Dynamic Form before. But if such a use case is considered, I think it's a pretty hard thing to setup and use. Although, if you're an enterprise and has several web projects where you're looking to provide a consistent look and feel to your components, then I guess this would be a pretty good option to go for.

**THE BAD:** Dynamic Forms are definitely great for architectural assessment. But they don't simplify the development process by eliminating most of the UI work. In fact, I'd say that there's more UI work when it comes to Reactive Forms. It's also a bit tricky to add validation errors, add/remove form controls or form groups from form arrays, get references to particular form controls or groups in the forms etc. So there's a bit of a learning curve over there. But once you've mastered Reactive Forms, they're pretty straightforward.

Again in the case of Dynamic Forms, it's quite fruitful if you want to have consistent forms throughout your enterprise. But that's not always the case depending on your enterprise type.

**WHEN TO USE WHICH:**

I disagree with your last statement though. Using a particular type of form would completely depend on the type of use case that you're trying to achieve.

If you have a very simple user onboarding form which accepts name and email from a user, then creating a reactive form for this won't make much sense.

But if you have data coming in from an API, you have a model for this data, and you want to make a form with this data pre-filled so that user can update it, then for such a use case, Reactive Forms are more preferred.

Hope this made some sense and helped you decide on what should be used when.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. Have you used Dynamic Forms? Are Dynamic Forms as capable as Reactive Forms?  If not then can Dynamic Forms be extended relatively easily to have the same capabilities as Reactive Forms?  Or are Dynamic Forms generally considered a nice time-saver to deliver some simple forms, with the understanding that the introduction of additional complexity will require that the input form be re-written as a Reactive input form?

Comment: Can you please point me to a link of where you've read the term Dynamic Form? I'm under the impression that Dynamic Forms and Reactive Forms are one and the same thing.

Comment: Sure here's the angular.io page: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form. The left nav Forms section describes "Template-driven Forms", "Reactive Forms" and "Dynamic forms."  But maybe the lowercase "f" in "Dynamic forms" indicates that "Dynamic forms" are a type of "Reactive forms" implementation. Will you please review and lmk?

Comment: Thanks Siddharth.  Although each type of input form has its advantages, it sounds like if I needed to choose a single form type for an app for consistency, then Reactive Forms would be the way to go